# Combining multiple data types into a single unified data structure in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables

In VB.NET I would like to create a complicated data structure with multiple types of data stored in an array like format (see below).

I am trying to create a data structure that would look something like this:

```
[Name; xLoc; yLoc; zLoc; [Jagged Array]]
```

Note: Name needs to be dimensioned as a string, xLoc and so forth as integers.
The Jagged Array would look like this:

```
[Array1;Array2;...]
```

Each Array within would look like:

```
[xVel; yVel; zVel]
```

Note: Each value in the above vector would be an integer.

An example of this data structure with data in it might look like this:

```
[Ship1; 15; 16; 25; [[2;3;0];[5;0;7];[6;2;1]]]
```

Essentially I want to create a jagged array with multiple types of data stored in the same structure.  Does VB.NET support this kind of structure in any way?  I am not very experienced with VB.NET so there might very well be a much more efficient way to structure the data that would do the same thing in VB.  Please feel free to comment with any ideas or critiques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)`, but you need to keep track of what the types are when you retrieve the values from the list.

Out of curiosity, why do you want to store different types together in the same list?

To use `System.Collections.Generic.List`

```
Dim x as new List(of Object)()

x.Add(element) 'given an element, all objects inherit from Object
x.Add(new Int32({1,2,3,4,5})
x.AddRange(array) 'append an array's contents

Dim retrievedValue as int32() = x(1) ' here, I needed to remember what I stored at what indice.
```

To make things easier, I would generally not do this kind of thing. You lose type safety and need to implicitly cast the value retrieved, but if you want to it can be done in the language.

I would think about how I could write a class that would represent the data I am working with. If a class is too heavyweight, perhaps a few strongly-typed Dictionary() objects that share keys to store say int32() and strings in a `string_map` and `int_array_map` respectively.

For instance, a Dictionary stores elements in KeyValuePairs, which can be strongly typed.

```
Dim dict as new Dictionary(of string, List(of int32))()
dict.Add('myname', new List(of Int32)({1,2,4,5,6,7})
```

So `dict('myname')` retrieves a strongly typed list of Int32.

I'm really just stabbing in the dark here, but you can see there are several useful collections classes in .NET. I'd recommend reading into the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Comment: I need to associate the values with each other and I don't want to keep track of a million individual dimentioned names for values.  For instance that data structure above represents on of like 30 items I want to keep track of.  Every element in each of those 30 arrays in related and pertinent to each of the others.  Think of it as a way to keep track of an excel spreadsheet where each array represents a row in the table.  If there is a better way of going about this please, let me know.

Comment: Also, how do you implement that structure?

Comment: Hmm, so with dictionaries you can create data structures of all one type (integers in this case) and refer to each dictionary with its string name?  That sounds exactly like what would be needed.  Only question though is, with dictionaries and I defining a way to store data, so i could define one dictionary with numerous 'myname' values, or would i need to create a new dictionary each time i wanted a new 'myname' value to refer to a list of integers.

Comment: Note that in the example I associate a list of int32 with a string key. Dictionaries are in most languages in some form these days, and can be overused in place of good OOP, but certainly have their purpose. Note that they mostly use a hash algorythm for lookup, and are therefore slower than pure arrays (but much more fun).

Comment: Sorry, yes a dictionary contains an arbitrary number of KeyValuePairs

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much for your help.  I got exactly what i needed with the dictionaries and I got to learn something.  Thanks for spending the time to follow up.  I wish I could do more besides up vote you answer and accept it :P

Comment: No problem! I'm glad if I was able to help.